# How do I connect to MySQL db hosted on cpanel in node js locally?

Tags: mysql, node.js, timeout, database-connection, cpanel

I have a database hosted on cpanel and I am not able to connect to it. I am using 'mysql' package in node js. It throws the timeout error.

```
function create_connect(){
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'domain name',
        user     : 'user',
        password : 'pass',
        database : 'dbname'
    });
    connection.connect((err)=>{
        if(err){console.log(err)}
        else{console.log('connected!')}
    });
    return connection;
}
```

Also my node js code is on local machine and i am trying to connect db on cpanel host. I tried using ipaddress instead of domain name and adding my ip to remote sql in cpanel. Timeout error still persists.
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at Connection._handleConnectTimeout

Answer (score 0):

If cpanel is installed by default, you can't connect by specifying ip/hostname, because you need to add a host as a specific ip or% of users to connect correctly. You can view users through the default phpadmin of cpanel, `select host,user from mysql.user;`

Comment: So,simply it is not possible to connect?